# Using 100% cpu vs using maximum available threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I made a Mandelbrot set visual presentation using POSIX thread library in C. The output is a .pgm file.
Upon thread implementation three case seems to pop up which are as follows:-

1. On using only 4-3 thread it works slow, but don't eat up my CPU usage
2. On using 20 thread it works well, but use 100%-98% of CPU usage
3. On using 40 thread it works slow, and is only using 25 threads (as shown by windows task manager/process manager)

So, is it wise to use less threads or the use that amount of threads which just touch 100% CPU usage or the use maximum number of threads offered by OS ?

I am using Intel Pentium 4 x86 (2GB RAM) machine and using Windows 7 Ultimate.

The Code for reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_ITR 100
#define MAX_UNSTABLE 4
#define Xin -1.5
#define Yin 1.0
#define Xf 0.5
#define Yf -1.0

char * arr;

void * function(void * arg)
{
    int width = *((int *)arg);
    int height = 8000;
    int count;
    double x=Xin, y=Yin;
    double xf = Xf, yf = Yf;
    
    double xinc = (xf-x)/(double)8000;
    double yinc = (yf-y)/(double)8000;
    double rr,ii,zr=0,zi=0,mag=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<height;i++,x=Xin + xinc*width,y+= yinc)
    {
        for(j=0+width;j<width+400;j++,x += xinc,count=-1,zr=0,zi=0)
        {
            mag=0;
            while((++count < MAX_ITR) && (mag < MAX_UNSTABLE))
            {
                rr = zr;
                ii = zi;         // square of Z
                zr = rr*rr - ii*ii;
                zi = 2*rr*ii;
                
                zr += x;
                zi += y;
                mag = pow(zr*zr + zi*zi,0.5);
            }
            arr[j + i * height] = 255 - (int)(count * 255/MAX_ITR);
        }
    }
    printf("\nthread id >%d\n",width/400 + 1);
    printf("xinc %f\nyinc %f\n",xinc,yinc);
    printf("from=>(%11.9f, %11.9f)\nto=>(%11.9f, %11.9f)\n",xinc*width,Yin,2*(xinc*width),Yf);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int width = 8000, height = 8000,i;
    arr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * width * height);
    pthread_t threadPoll[20];
    int set[20] = {0};
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        set[i] = 400*i;
        printf("%d ",set[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(threadPoll[i]), NULL, function, &(set[i]));
    }
    
    for(i=19;i>0;i--)
    {
        pthread_join(threadPoll[i],NULL);
    }
    
    FILE * fp = (FILE*)fopen("out.pgm","wb");
    if(fp == NULL)return 1;
    fprintf(fp,"P5\n%d %d\n255\n",width,height);
    fwrite(arr,sizeof(char)*width*height,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("done!");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer is going to be "it depends".

Comment: if this is the only thing that will be running in your target, then use 100% of it.

Comment: It seems like if you add more threads you add more work, so the code will run slower. I presume those constants depend on each other. If you rewrite the code to depend on a NUM_THREADS constant we could play with the performance better. For example, `int width = 8000` is probably `int width = NUM_THREADS * 400`?

Comment: Is it your top priority to have the program finish its computation as quickly as possible, or is it more important to have the program use a limited amount of CPU power (e.g. so it can run in the background without draining the user's battery very much, and/or without affecting the performance of other programs that might be running simultaneously?).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the goal is to complete as soon as possible. The main question is to use maximum number of threads or to use that particular number of threads that just touch 100% cpu usage (like 10-9 i.e less than 20) . Suppose 12 threads take 100% cpu usage and 20 threads also, which will be better to use (important to consider the fact array partition a single thread need to do)

Comment: In that case, a good rule of thumb is to use the same number of threads as your hardware has CPU cores... but the only real test is to time your program with various numbers of threads and see how its performance is different with each thread-count.